# (possibly duplicated question) Prove the Cauchy theorem using mathematical induction

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

[image: Here is a screen shoot at an e-book.]

Here are some of my questions:
1) If the order of G is one, then there is no such p as stated in the above article, so why say that the theorem is true here?
2) where exactly is the starting point? It seems to be the fact that the theorem is true for all subgroups of G of order less than that of G. But this is not proven in the article.

This question may have been asked by someone before, but I don't know where to find it, so I post this anyway. I know this question is kind of tricky, but I do hope someone could help me out. thank you.

Comment: (1) The condition then is fulfilled vacuously, and (2) This is precisely the inductive hypothesis.

Comment: 1 is not a prime number is it?, and the order of G is 1, so no such a p, the theorem is failed.

Comment: no: the argument is: find me a prime dividing $\;1\;$ and I'll present you an element of order that prime. There is no such prime! Good, then you can **not** refute the above argument. This is what's called "true or fulfilled vacuously".

Comment: To see what is happening, note that the theorem here can be restated in a form which refers to "all $p$" - For all primes $p$, if $p$ divides $|G|$ then $G$ has an element of order $p$. So in the case $|G|=1$ I take a prime $p$ - the group of order $1$ does not have an element of that order - so the theorem is true for that prime. Since this is true for any $p$ I choose, it is true for all $p$, which makes the thorem true in the case $|G|=1$

Comment: Ok, now, The next step is to show that if the theorem is true for the case where the order of G is k, then we can conclude that the theorem is true for the case where the order of G is k+1, right? But the method doesn't seem to be used here.

Comment: This is using a form of "strong induction" where the inductive hypothesis is assumed to be true for all smaller integers - in particular for the orders of proper subgroups and quotient groups of $|G|$ - the proof needs it true for $|N|$ and $|G|/|N|$ for any proper subgroup $N$ of $G$.

Comment: This [seems to be from](http://www.google.com/search?q=Cauchy+%22Before+getting+involved+with+the+proof%22) (some edition of) Hestein's Abstract Algebra. I think that it is good mention the book where the materials come from. For people who have access to that book this provides more context. (For example, they can see what has been proved before.) There is also a [discussion on meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1805/on-the-inclusion-of-pages-of-text-as-images-in-questions) about embedding the whole pages from books as images in the post.

Comment: @MartinSleziak This is a book from I.N.Herstein. I forgot to mention where it came from.